# mongo db aggregate match using value from collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql, match, aggregate

How can I match a field in MongoDB with value from another field of the same collection.

For example from the collection test: (not exactly the same collection but it serves the need)

test:

```
{
    "a" : "one",
    "b" : "two",
    "c" : "three"
    "d" : "one"
}
```

I need to fetch document where value of 'a' matches the value of 'd'.
I tried:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match:{a:'$d'}}
])
```

but no hope!!!

Comment: You need to use the `$expr` (and aggregation operators) to match two fields within the document.

Comment: You can even use the matching in a `find` method (instead of an aggregation match) when used with `expr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$a",
          "$d"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vg2fTiL6-ok)**